# How to encode string as zlib stream

Tags: python-3.x, encode, zlib

How can I convert a string like this "`x+)JMU05�d040031Q��(ILNN-.f�I~��n�ȷ����M`" to a zlib stream?

I have this code that doesn't work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zlib

resp = requests.get( url )
bfs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html5lib")

print(zlib.decompress(bfs.text))


TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Where does the `content` come from?

Comment: @DYZ BeautifulSoup object that I convert into a string.

Comment: `decompress` expects a bytes-like object, not a string. Perhaps you should have not converted it.

Comment: @DYZ TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'BeautifulSoup'

Comment: It may help if you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DYZ Let me know if it's enough information to test!